# how should a google API key be presented to phonegapBuild to an build iOS app?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, phonegap-build

my starting point is html5 code (which works fine when served to a browser). To then build an iOS app, I'm not using phonegap locally, I just upload to phonegapBuild, install my apple credentials, and attempt to run the app on my iphone. The app loads, begins to execute, and then presents a popup saying that google does not like my API key.

The key is of type 'simple API access' pointing at my iOS app ID.

I am presenting the key in the head of the .html when I request the google maps v3 API. I suspect this is wrong based on the instructions in [https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start] referring to an *xCode* built app: "Finally, add your API key to your AppDelegate." I am trying to avoid xCode. I'm thinking there must be some config.xml magic necessary to pull this off.

So, how should vanilla html5+config.xml present a google API key to phonegapBuild to build an iOS app?

(please see screenshots on [http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/how_should_google_api_keys_be_handed_to_phonegapbuild_for_incorporation_into_an_html5_based_app_for_ios] )

Comment: after a day of testing with the help of adobe support people, it looks like the problem relates to the 'iOS applications' specification of the google API key. right now, I'm thinking this is a phonegapBuild issue. More info to come after I present my evidence to adobe.

Comment: adobe replies: "Use the JavaScript/ Web Browser API Key.
Allow all websites access to it." [http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/how_should_google_api_keys_be_handed_to_phonegapbuild_for_incorporation_into_an_html5_based_app_for_ios?utm_content=reply_link&utm_medium=email&utm_source=reply_notification#reply_13906296]